# Persist data for 24 hours

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, redis, microservices

I need to build a microservice that scrapes a message once a day and persists it *somewhere*. It does not need to be accessible after 24 hours (it can be deleted). It doesn't really matter where or how, but I need to access it from an Express.js endpoint and return the message. Currently we use Redis and MongoDB for data persistence. It feels wrong to create a whole collection for one tiny service, and I'm not sure of an application of Redis that would fulfill this task. What's my best option? Open to any suggestions, thank you!

Comment: Why not just put some JSON in a file?

Comment: @jfriend00 Heroku. We run everything on Heroku which, as you may know, uses ephemeral storage.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having a single document in a collection - as long as it fulfills an application's functionality (persisting, querying, deleting, etc.). Are you using a whole MongoDB database installation for this purpose _or_ is it just an existing database with another collection?

Comment: Well, then please add that information about Heroku  and no persistent file storage to your question so the full context is in your question itself.

Comment: You can set ttl value in redis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use YUGABYTE DB,  and you can set TABLE LIVE= 24 Hours, then data will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Redis provide an expiration mechanism out of the box. You can associate a timeout to a key, and it will be automatically deleted after the timeout has expired. Some official documentation [here](https://redis.io/commands/expire)

Redis also provides logical databases, if you want to keep this expiring keys separated from the rest of your application. So you do not need to spin up another machine. Some official documentation [here](https://redis.io/commands/select)